# How to vectorize (simeple eg.) arrays for POWER ISA using inline assembly

Tags: vectorization, inline-assembly, powerpc

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to add,multiply, or implement any number of POWER8 vector instructions using GCC's inline assembly. Hopefully someone here can give me a few examples how this looks in the context of GCC's inline assembly - I'm specifically target POWER ISA. Any links to tutorials or further reading is much much appreciated!

So, i'm totally new to writing any assembly and I started reading IBM inline assembly tutorials but they only cover the very basic cases of loading storing and manipulating immediate values and I didn't find anything relating to vector instructions which is what I'm after.

Say I have 2 input arrays v1,v2 and 1 output array v3, I want to add them using vector instructions, what does that look like?

I have something like:

```
int main(void)
{
    float v1[8];
    float v2[8];
    float v3[8];

    int i=0;

    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        v1[i] = 1.1;
        v2[i] = 3.3;
        v3[i] = 0.0;
        printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f\n", v1[i], v2[i], v3[i]);
    }

    __asm__("before:");
    __asm__("vaddfp %0,%1,%2\n\t"
        : "=wf"(v3[0])
        : "wf"(v1[0]), "wf"(v2[0]));
    __asm__("vaddfp %0,%1,%2\n\t"
            : "=wf"(v3[4])
            : "wf"(v1[4]), "wf"(v2[4]));
    __asm__("after:");

    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        printf("\n%.2f %.2f %.2f\n", v1[i], v2[i], v3[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This actually does modify v3[0,4] but all other regions are left untouched.

EDIT:
Turns out I used the wrong constraint, and the wrong instruction.
The below code does what I envisioned, a simple add two vectors example using a vector instruction.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    float *sv1, *sv2, *sv3;
    sv1 = calloc(4, sizeof(float));
    sv2 = calloc(4, sizeof(float));
    sv3 = calloc(4, sizeof(float));
    vector float *v1;
    vector float *v2;
    vector float *v3;

    v1 = (vector float*) &(sv1[0]);
    v2 = (vector float*) &(sv2[0]);
    v3 = (vector float*) &(sv3[0]);
    long i=0;

    /* populate the data */
    printf("before\n");
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        sv1[i] = 1.1;
        sv2[i] = 2.2;
        sv3[i] = 0.0;
        printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f\n", sv1[i], sv2[i], sv3[i]);
    }

    __asm__("before:");
    __asm__("xvaddsp %0,%1,%2\n\t"
           : "=wf"(v3[0])
           : "wf"(v1[0]), "wf"(v2[0]));
    __asm__("after:");

    printf("after\n");
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f\n", sv1[i], sv2[i], sv3[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about ppc. But looking at [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/gcc/+/009f97f2bf0e7c070fac2d2806af05e166ceaf3c/gcc/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/testsuite/gcc.target/powerpc/ppc-target-4.c) code, I wonder if you can use vec_add (aka __builtin_vec_add) instead of trying to coax inline asm to do what you need. If you absolutely must use inline asm, maybe start with [PowerPC constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) (scroll down) and gcc's [asm docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). BTW `ISA` tag seems wrong.

Comment: Thanks David, aren't the built-ins compiler dependent? (As I'm typing this I'm realizing that just about only compiler I care is gcc - so yeah, I think using built ins may work.